# BizTalk - Looping

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm working on a project which requires to fetch the records from the file and update the same into active directory.

I am able to update single record into Active directory but not able to update multiple records.

I know we have to apply loop concept but problem is I have no idea of how to use loop concept in Orchestration and which condition has to be used.

Comment: Suggest you check this question's answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485238/how-to-loop-in-orchestration-biztalk-2010

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I'm assuming you are not asking about how to iterate through records, there are many examples out there about how to do this.  If you have to iterate through a lot of records, I'd recommend implementing it in a custom class or using the `XmlReceive` pipeline to do so.  For someone newer to BizTalk though, it might not be immediately obvious how to combine a Decision and a Loop shape....

---

There are.. a lot of ways to do this.  You can go with a `Loop` shape that has a `Decision` shape within it.  This works just like a normal loop, but you only do any processing/sending if the desired condition is met.  You could think of it like this kind of C# code:

```
while(condition == true)
{
    if (anotherCondition == true)
    {
        CreateAndSendMessage();
    }
    UpdateCondition();
}
```

[image: conditional loop]